# Playing an MP3 file using Python

Tags: python, audio, python-tesseract

I'm working on a project to convert texts into audio as in the following code. It is working fine, but I want to play the MP3 file without opening media player. How can I do that?

The code:

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract
from gtts import gTTS
import os

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
img = cv2.imread('1.png')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
X= pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
language = 'en'
myobj = gTTS(text=X, lang=language, slow=False)
myobj.save("welcome.mp3")
os.system("welcome.mp3")
```

Comment: Is this a tensorflow question ?

Comment: Kindly refer to this stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20021547/11652623

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the `playsound` module

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound("audio_file.mp3")
```

Comment: i did but it gives me an erreo like this  Error 259 for command:
        play welcome.mp3 wait
    The driver cannot recognize the specified command parameter.

Comment: citing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68704443/python-playsound-error-261-for-command-the-driver-cannot-recognize-the-specifie): try uninstalling it and then installing a previous version (with `pip install playsound==1.2.2`). The latest version seems to have broken something in some systems

Comment: Did the downgraded version work?